# Can weakValues() and expireAfterAccess() be combined?

Tags: guava, google-guava-cache

I want to do something like this:

```
 CacheBuilder
            .newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(CONFIG.cacheMaxSize())
            .expireAfterAccess(CONFIG.cacheTimeout(),
                                CONFIG.cacheTimeUnit())
            .weakValues()
            .build(cacheLoader);
```

The behavior I expect is that an entry will only be expired if the value is not referenced AND the expiration time has passed. Is that how this usage will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not directly, since the weak value can be garbage collected as soon as there are no more strong references to the object. What you could do however is use a [`ForwardingCache`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/ForwardingCache.html) backed by two separate caches, a weak-value cache and a timed-expiry cache, so that the time-based cache holds a strong reference to the object thereby keeping it in the weak-value cache. It'd look something like this:

```
public class WeakValuedExpiringCache<K, V> extends ForwardingCache<K, V> {
  private final Cache<K, V> expiringCache;
  private final Cache<K, V> weakCache;

  public WeakValuedExpiringCache(CacheBuilder expiringSpec) {
    expiringCache = expiringSpec.build();
    weakCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().weakValues().build();
  }

  // weakCache is the canonical cache since it will hold values longer than
  // expiration if there remain other strong references
  protected Cache<K, V> delagate() {
    return weakCache;
  }

  @override
  public V get(K key, Callable<? extends V> valueLoader)
     throws ExecutionException {
    // repopulate the expiring cache if needed, and update the weak cache
    V value = expiringCache.get(key, valueLoader);
    weakCache.put(key, value); // don't call super.put() here
  }

  @Override
  public void put(K key, V value) {
    expiringCache.put(key, value);
    super.put(key, value);
  }

  // Handle putAll(), cleanUp(), invalidate(), and invalidateAll() similarly
}
```

You can do the same thing with a [`ForwardingLoadingCache`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/ForwardingLoadingCache.html) as well, just like `.get()` above you should load the value from the `expiringCache` and `.put()` it into the `weakCache` in the relevant loading methods.

Comment: Thank you! That's perfect. And you saw into my question that I meant that there should be no other references to the value BESIDES the cache. I hadn't thought through that a weak reference won't ever prevent gc.

Answer (score 1):

No, an entry will expire if the value is not referenced OR the expiration time has passed:

```java
public class CacheBuilderIT {
    @Test
    public void expireAfterAccessWithWeakValues() throws InterruptedException {
        Cache<Object, Object> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                .expireAfterAccess(500, MILLISECONDS)
                .weakValues()
                .build();
        Object key = new Object();
        Object value = new Object(); // keep a strong reference to the value
        cache.put(key, value);
        Thread.sleep(300);
        assert cache.getIfPresent(key) != null : "expiration occurred too quickly";
        Thread.sleep(300);
        assert cache.getIfPresent(key) != null : "last access did not reset expiration";
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        assert cache.getIfPresent(key) != null : "reference did not prevent expiration";
    }
}
```

Ouptut:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: reference did not prevent expiration
```